# How to sort cgridview column which have HAS_MANY relation?

Tags: sorting, yii, cgridview

I need to sort a column in yii (CGridView) which have HAS_MANY relationship. any one can help me about this.

**Here is my CGRIDVIEW column:**

```
 array(
     'name' => 'emp_cat_id',
     'type' => 'Raw',
     'value' => '$data->getProjectContactClasses($data)',
     'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '350'),
),
```

**Here is my Function to get ProjectContactClasses in model**

```
public function getProjectContactClasses($model)
    {      
        $classes = "";
        if (!empty($model->emp_cat_id))
        {
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->addInCondition("id", array($model->emp_cat_id));
            $model = LaborClassification::model()->findAll($criteria);

            if (count($model) > 0)
            {
                foreach ($model as $row)
                {
                    $classes .= $row->classification . ", ";
                }
                $classes = substr($classes, 0, -2);
            }
        }
        return $classes;
    }
```

**Here is the relationship**

```
'project_contacts' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProjectContact', 'project_id'),
```

---

Do let me know if any one need more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'attributes'=>array(
                'emp_cat_id.labor_lassification'=>array(
                    'asc'=>'emp_cat_id.labor_lassification',
                    'desc'=>'emp_cat_id.labor_lassification DESC',
                ),
                '*',
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: Mudassar! Thanks for your answer.

but i think its for one to one relation not for has many relation.

Comment: yes it for one to one relation let me check if i can help for has many relation